# Generic parameter constrained by other generic parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Due to Swift's lack of covariance, I needed some workaround. I'm coming from Java world, so I instinctively tried to create constraint from one type to other generic type.

So I wrote the following class:

```
class Factory<T: AnyObject> {
    let factoryClosure: () -> T

    init(closure: () -> T) {
        factoryClosure = closure
    }

    init<CHILD: T>(childFactory: Factory<CHILD>) {
        factoryClosure = { () -> T in
            return otherFactory.create()
        }
    }

    func create() -> T {
        return factoryClosure()
    }
}
```

I expected this to work just fine. I have the `T` defined and `CHILD` should be a subclass of `T`. Swift compiler however disagrees and shows the following error on the line with `init<CHILD: T>`.

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'T'

I tried the generic parameter inheritance in different scenario as well. Adding the following method into the class (and removing the init that was causing the compile error).

```
func to<OTHER where OTHER: AnyObject, T: OTHER>() {

}
```

This yields basically the same output.

> Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol type 'OTHER'

Anything I though may work did not and ended with similar error message. Is this a bug in Swift? Or am I missing something? Or is it a feature of Swift and will never work as I thought?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve?  The actual goal that is, rather than some code that is trying to achieve said unstated goal.

Comment: The goal I'm trying to achieve is to have something that would allow me workaround missing covariance (if I recall that term correctly). In Java I would use `Factory<? extends MyObject>` and could pass in any instance of `Factory` which would have type parameter of `MyObject` or its children.

Comment: That still sounds like a means not an end. What's the actual goal?

Comment: Right, sorry I didn't get you at first. The goal is a dependency injection of some kind. I want to have dependencies as initializer params. Either instance itself or a factory that I can call later to get an instance. The problem is in the latter because when I have `init(someFactory: Factory<Some>` I can't pass it `Factory<MockSome>`.

Comment: http://typhoonframework.org is a dependency injection framework

Comment: @Jeef Thanks, I know that one, but it needs you to use NSObject as your base object which is something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Using pure swift DOES have limitations with generics - although it does give you a performance increase

Comment: Could you just use protocols instead of subclassing as the compilers hints?

Comment: I could not find any way to make one type parameter to be constrained by another type parameter. The parameter is not a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass any `Factory<T>` where `T` is of type `AnyObject` you just have to write:

```
init(childFactory: Factory<T>) {
    factoryClosure = { () -> T in
        return otherFactory.create()
    }
}
```

because T is automatically constrained by your class.

Comment: This will not solve the problem, because you would be only able to pass in a `Factory<T>` and not `Factory<Z>` where `Z` is a subclass of `T`.

Comment: I think this solves your problem because if `Z` is a subclass of `T` it is also of type `AnyObject`. Therefore you can also pass `Factory<Z>` (`T` is just a placeholder for a type which conforms to `AnyObject`)

Comment: In the context, `T` is already constrained by the class you are creating. So if you do `let zFactory = Factory<Z>() { return Z() };   let tFactory = Factory<T>(childFactory: zFactory)` it will not work.